# When will Salesforce Code Builder be Generally available and how to get access before becoming GA?

Tags: developer-productivity, code-builder

Salesforce has announced Code Builder few days ago but there is no information of its general avaialbility in that announcement. Being able to use VS Code features from browser is exiting and I cann't wait to get hands on Code Builder.

Any idea of when will Salesforce Code Builder be Generally available? How to get access before becoming GA in developer/partner Org?

Announcement: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/06/introducing-code-builder.html

Comment: While it's not officially released yet, it is based on GitHub Codespaces, so you can have a play if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code Builder is now generally available in all the paid salesforce orgs. You can read about the announcements [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2023/10/salesforce-code-builder-is-now-generally-available).

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Right now, this feature is in Pilot. Contact your Account Executive if you'd like to be a part of the Pilot, they can sign you up. As far as GA, there's no announced date. It may come out in the next release, next year, or never (or anywhere in between). This depends on how well the pilot goes, how many bugs need to be fixed, if it's commercially viable, etc. If you're in the pilot, you'll probably be able to get more information about the roadmap, since details like this are only disclosed under NDA and an understanding that everything is tenative.

Answer (score 4):

Update - Looks like it got delayed:

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/12/an-update-on-code-builder-and-the-future-of-tooling-at-salesforce

> ...we’re making significant changes to the product we piloted this
> Summer, based on feedback from Pilot participants. The resulting
> product will be even more unified with the complete Salesforce
> Platform, and delivered with the highest expectations for trust and
> availability. An unfortunate reality of this change is that we must
> delay the Code Builder Beta...